# django.core.management not found but django exists when running manage.py

Tags: python, django

When running this command in my virtual environment:

```
sudo ./manage.py migrate wifipromo 0088_auto__add_adgrouptimesets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I get the error above. I checked the shebang in manage.py its "#!/usr/bin/env python" which should be correct.

Additionally when I enter the python console, I can run the following....

```
(ve)ubuntu@app02:/var/apps/nimbus/nimbus$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Feb 27 2014, 19:43:51)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/var/apps/nimbus/environments/767a6ca970ca5b5cc5724c3e158f8f53/ve/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
>>> django.get_version()
'1.4'
```

which is strange. Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: You can also do `pip freeze` for a list of dependencies and versions in the current virtualenv

Comment: are you using virtualenv while running the migrate ? Also, if you are running the migrations as sudo, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: can you show us the code in the manage.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the app I sshed into was configured for a specific user. Ubuntu and root aren't configured correctly. This turned out to be a very specific domain problem and I guess its not a good format for this site. Sorry. Thanks for helping everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You're running with sudo (user `root`), so it can not get info from your virtualenv (user `ubuntu`). Try to run `migrate` as normal user.